How to have indirect lightning bounce properly within volumetrics?
I'm looking for a way to do bounce light without relying on light bouncing off of objects. Because normally, if light is aimed towards a sphere but there's no ground or other object for light to bounce back from, the unlit part of the sphere will receive no light, assuming there's no background light.

One thing I tried was to have a object with a volumetric scatter shader and a light-path node for camera ray connected to the factor of a mix node (and the scatter node connected to the second shader input) covering the entire scene, which did get close to what I wanted: but the issue with volumetric scatter is that the light gets weaker the farther it gets from the light source, even if it wouldn't do so without the volume. I found this issue is fixed if I turn off shadows on the light object, but that has it's own issue of well, the light no longer casting shadows on objects.
I also tried swapping the connection so that the scatter volume was connected to the first shader input, and I would get something like this:

I tried looking up if it was possible to bake lightning to a volumetric, but to no avail.
Another thing I tried was to have an emissive cone the same shape of the light cone, then hide the cone from camera rays; it works pretty well for objects outside the cone, but anything inside the cone would be lacking in shadows.
I am willing to attempt open shading language if it's the only option.

Seems to work fine without any extra effort:

That's simple Volume Scatter shader in the World node tree:

And just make sure you have enough volume bounces:

It doesn't need to be anything this crazy as 64, 3 - 8 would probably be enough for most things.
Not sure if I understand what you want to do correctly, but you can hide the volume itself if you want:


This is not too different from one of the things I tried, and it would work perfectly, but unfortunately, if I have shadows on, then light passing through a volume gets weaker the further the distance. If I turn shadows off, the previous issue gets fixed but then there's no shadows.

Sorry, but this is a question and answer platform about using Blender, not a place to complain about how physics and light works. Yes, the further something is away from a light source the less light reaches it. If you want this effect to be weaker have a very strong light very far away - that way, the distances in your scene are smaller fractions of the distance from the light and light falloff in the distances meaningful in relation to your scene is weaker. You can also fake lighting effects with other light sources in your scene - nothing wrong with that if it gives you results you want.

I believe I found a solution to my own problem.

Somehow, by connecting "Is Diffuse Ray" to a mix shader with the volume scatter connected to the second shader input, the light bounces around almost exactly how I want it to.
(Btw this requires having a diffuse bounce higher than 0. Volume bounces don't seem to make a difference even at 0, but I would put them to something like 4 anyways).

